# Unwanted space around Nav

Tags: html, css

I am new here and I am also creating my very first site from scratch.

As shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtZE2.png), the nav bar at the top has space above and below it, which I don't want. I have tried removing/adding padding to the .nav ul but it doesn't seem to work.

What part of my HTML/CSS is responsible for this and how can I fix it? Thank you!

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}

div {
    display: block;
}

.header {
    background-color: #333333;
}

.nav {
    padding:  0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav ul {
    padding: 20;
}

.nav ul li {
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px 30px 20px 10px ;
    font-family: serif;
    font-weight: 200;
}

.second_section .container {
    background-image: url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-    I0jOcWYqW94/UdFZ9U8Si0I/AAAAAAAACRw/2Hhb0xY7yzY/s1600/84.jpg);
    height: 900px;
}

.copy {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 100px 50px 500px 500px;
    color: white;
    font-family: garamond;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li>ABOUT</li>
            <li>WORK</li>
            <li>TEAM</li>
            <li>CONTACT</li>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="second_section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="copy">
            <h1>ACTUATE CONTENT</h1>
            <h3>Expert content for every business</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no image, a problem could be that you didn't close the `ul` tag

Comment: I think now you understood properly. Then don't forgot to mark/accept any of the answer which solve your issue by clicking on right symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give following css will remove all default margin and padding which browser taking on top of the css.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gvdujdzc/1/)**

Comment: This worked but I am wondering doesn't the html, body { } cover all elements?

Comment: @DrEvil No man. Every element have there own `margin` and `padding`

Comment: @DrEvil : `html { ... }` covers only the `<html>` element and `body { ... }` covers only the `<body>` element, just like `p { ... }` covers only `<p>` elements or  `div { ... }` covers only `<div>` elements. `* { ... }` covers all elements.

Comment: @ketan Oh ok, I thought that html, body covered all child tags.

Comment: @DrEvil : If you want to cover all ancestors of the body element, you could do `body * { ... }`. If you want to cover all children of the body element, you could do `body > * { ... }`. etc. For an overview of the different kinds of selectors, check out http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp.

Comment: Thanks John, will check it out

Answer (score 1):

### Solution :

This should do it :

```
.nav ul {
    margin: 0;
}
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/10djj33q/1/) for a demo.

---

#### Notes :

- The `padding: 20;` you set for `.nav ul` won't have any effect, because padding requires a unit to follow your value. You probably want something like `padding: 20px;` or `padding: 1.25em;` instead.
- `font-weight: 20;` won't have any effect either. Valid values for font-weight are `normal`, `bold`, `bolder`, `lighter`, `100`, `200`, `300`, `400`, `500`, `600`, `700`, `800` and `900`.

Comment: Yeah, I see that, it's a newb mistake. :) I'll correct those, thanks!